# how to delete outlook inbox subfolder contents using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

there must be a way of doing this using the MAPI.

I have

```
    $ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
    $inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
    $inbox.Folders `
| ? name -eq Subfolder1 ` 
| % Items
```

There must be a way of deleting the contents of this subfolder folder after the full script runs, so the subfolder is clear for the next time the script runs to process only the items as they come in new. (so as not to have processed files reprocessing). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use the Delete Method:

```
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder('olFolderInbox')
$SubFolders = $inbox.Folders
```

To Delete all the Subfolders with the contents:

```
$SubFolders | % {$_.Delete()}
```

To Delete only The Contents

```
foreach ($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
{
    While ($Subfolder.Items.Count -ne 0)
    {
    $SubFolder.Items | % {$_.delete()}
    }
}
```

- Note: for some reason, sometimes it's not deleting all the items, This can be solved in a simple `While Loop`, like in the example